# loading soundcloud html5widget causing https/http error

Tags: iframe, https, soundcloud

I'm trying to load the html5widget using an iframe, but even if I use `http://w.soundcloud.com/` I get the error that i can't load and https connection from an http page. How can I solve this? Why is soundcloud redirecting to a secure connection?

Tnx

EDIT:

I'm using safari and getting this error: `[Error] Blocked a frame with origin "https://w.soundcloud.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://dev.norwegiansounds.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.`

When I'm using firefox there is no problem widget.

Here is an example:

http://dev.norwegiansounds.com/projects/93/

EDIT 2:
I've still not solved this. I've tried to create a completely blank file and copy the general iframe embed code without editing it, and I still get the same error. This is only a problem in safari on mac. Not on my phone, or firefox.

Comment: What browser are you using? The `https://soundcloud.com` sites are sending a `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` header, so no wonder you can't embed them using an iframe, but the `https://w.soundcloud.com` don't, so there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Anyone? I'm using `https://w.soundcloud.com` and `http://w.soundcloud.com`, but getting the same error.

Comment: I also sometimes get this error: `[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 (Bad Request) (plays, line 0)`
And sometimes it still plays, but mostly it doesn't...
Is there another place I can ask this question?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and finally I solved it adding a delay before executing the widget loading code.

I had this code in my document.ready,

```
var player = SC.Widget($('iframe.sc-widget')[0]);
```

and I transformed it in :

```
setTimeout(function () {
      var player = SC.Widget($('iframe.sc-widget')[0]);
}, 3000);
```

I implemented this custom soundcloud player using this delay instead of document ready and it works.
https://codepen.io/nickcolley/pen/uoCIy